# sys_file_metadata table extended but field not showing

Tags: file, typo3, content-management-system, flexform

I have extended the sys_file_metadata table by adding one additional column. Newly entered column is present in the table, but the field is not showing in flexform. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please describe how you have added this field. Show us the TCA Code, so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: I've listed my code below. 

        'protected_file' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:spt_downloads/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_sptdownloads_domain_model_downloadmanager.protected_file',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'items' => [
                    '1' => [
                        '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => 0,
            ]
            
        ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add you field to the TCA colums and to the `showitem`:

```
<?php

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;

defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

$tempColumns = [
    'protected_file' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:spt_downloads/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_sptdownloads_domain_model_downloadmanager.protected_file',
        'config'  => [
            'type'    => 'check',
            'items'   => [
                '1' => [
                    '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                ]
            ],
            'default' => 0,
        ]
    ]
];

ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_metadata', $tempColumns);
ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file_metadata', 'protected_file');
```

It's important not to forget the `addTCAcolumns` and `addToAllTCAtypes`. The first one add your field to the TCA and the second one make the field visible into the editor of your element by puttin it into `showitem` of the tca.

You have also put this code into `spt_downloads/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_metadata.php`. The use of this code in an `ext_tables.php` is deprecated and dont work anymore.